# Retrieve data from SQL in Marathi Language in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image: Please find the image of table]
I am developing a windows application based using C#. I want to take input from user in Marathi language and save the same in SQL server database. Also retrieve the data from SQL server in Marathi language. I tried using following query but it didn't worked. So my question is how can I save and retrieve it as it is?

For example:

```
Select Company from Master_Item where Item_Name =  'मोबाईल'
```

Comment: So..? Did you tried it and didn't work? You don't _even_ ask a question.

Comment: And what exactly is the question? Is something not working as expected?

Comment: Please find the image. I want to fetch company name and above query is not working for it.

Comment: @HemantSonar - I guess you got the answer

Comment: Yes. I got the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `N` before the value and the datatype  should be `nvarchar`.

```
Select Company from Master_Item where Item_Name =  N'मोबाईल'
```

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/305931/Save-Hindi-Marthi-Content-in-Sql-Server-database